# jquery puff effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 issues using hide/show puff effect on an opaque centered Div;-

On both showing and hiding, the div moves to the left of the screen before the action is performed. On hiding only, the opacity is removed and the div shows as a solid color just before hiding.

Below is the script, same issues in FF/Opera/Chrome/safari on Mac

```
<style type="text/css">
#toggledDiv{
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid red;
margin:0 auto;
left:0;
right:0;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.40;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(function() {    
$("#tgBtn").toggle(function(){
    $("#toggledDiv").show( "puff",{ }, 750 );
},function(){
  $("#toggledDiv").hide( "puff",{ }, 750 );
});
});

</script> 


<body> 
 <button id="tgBtn">Toggle</button> 
 <div id="toggledDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

Well , you have a few problems there. To avoid the flickering when you first press the toggle button just invert the order of hide & show in the toggle function.

To center the div you're doing it wrong. This is the easiest way to center elements, and it always works. Your div will no longer shift to the sides.

```
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -250px /* Half the width */
}
```

For the opacity to work with the animation you'll need to do it with jQuery too. I did it as callback functions but you can do it altogether.

As a side note, when you declare `position: absolute` you don't need `display: block`, it's implied.

Check a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/q7FcA/5/

Comment: Thanks for the example elclanrs - helped alot esp the centering trick. It appears that puff automatically changes opacity to 100% when it runs (could it be considered a bug?), doesn't seem to be a way around it so I'll just have to live with it.